# A result on convergence of series of positive terms

Tags: calculus

Just recently I learned from a highschooler I help in her Calculus class about a  convergence test for series with positive terms, and and of which  I was not aware. The test is a hybrid between the ratio and root test:

> *Theorem:* Suppose $a_n>0$ for all $n$.
>
> 1. If $\limsup_n\Big(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\Big)^n<\frac1e$, then the  series $\sum_na_n$ converges.
> 2. If there is $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$, $\Big(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\Big)^n\geq\frac1e$, then the series $\sum_na_n$ diverges.

By working some examples out: $\sum_n\frac{1}{n}$, $\sum_n\frac{1}{n^p}$, and the hypergeometric series $_2F_1(a,b,c;z)$, one can see that this result is more powerful that the usual ratio test, in fact it at the same hierarchy level as Raabe's test (in the De Morgan hierarchy).

My question is if anyone knows of the provenance of this result. Is is some sort of a folklore theorem?

My highschooler learned it from the following  [link](https://math.fel.cvut.cz/en/mt/txte/2/txe3ea2d.htm), which is the English translation to this other [link](https://math.fel.cvut.cz/mt/txte/2/txc3ea2d.htm) in Czech.   I look in several classic Soviet, French and American Calculus textbooks (including translations of the seminal books of Knopp), and the result was not presented neither in the textbook nor the problem companions.

Comment: It is also not present in Konrad Knopp's *Theory and Application of Infinite Series*.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: I looked at Knoop's book too.From our esteemed Dave L. Renfro [see his posting [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4673148/121671)) it seems that the result is *relatively recent": Orrin Frink, A ratio test, Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society 54 #10 (October 1948), p. 953, several years after K. Knopp wrote his books (in German).The English translations are faithful to the original and do not contain additional material (*continued*)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: (continuation) From comments in the posting I linked above, it seems that this result is closely related to Rabbe's test (both can be set as comparison test against the power series $\sum_nn^{-p}$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am not amazed by the fact that Dave L. Renfro was the one who wrote that.